# Compiling Inheritance program C++

Tags: c++, compilation

I've constructed a program that has a class called Message. There's another class called Topic that inherits from the Message class.

My question is, what's the best way to compile just the Topic class into an object file without making an executable??

Is it g++ Topic.cpp Message.cpp main.cpp?

I'm pretty sure that^ creates and executable. So is there any other way to compile JUST the Topic class, and NOT create an executable?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't there a manual for gcc somewhere on the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-c` option to compile a file without linking it:

```
g++ -c Topic.cpp
```

This will produce a `Topic.o`.

Comment: Isn't the .o file an output file?
What if I don't want an output file?

Comment: It's an object file, which is what you asked for.